# Is Java class in certain parent package?

Tags: java, package

I have package :

```
com.google.*.*.*
```

There may be many subpackages.

I have a Class `foo.java`

How to check if its inside the main package `com.google`

When I use `Class.getPackage()`, it gives only the whole package like this:
    `com.google.util.domain.sup`

Must I really use functions like : `substring() , split()`. Or is there a fancy way to check if it belongs to certain parent packages?

Comment: Its even worse, if the class was loaded by a custom class loader (that implemenets only the bare minimum to get the class into the VM), getPackage() may even return NULL. Happened to me - big WTF when the NullPointerException popped up.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say you have the .java file. So you can look at the package statement in the source code. The package won't change between compilation and execution. Why do you need a runtime solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean like...

```
if (getClass().getName().startsWith("com.google."))
```

if you need an exact match you can use

```
if (getClass().getPackage().getName().equals("com.google.util.domain.sup"))
```

Answer (score 7):

Packages are not hierarchical in Java. `com.google.foo` has nothing to do with package `com.google`. So if your goal is to check that a class is in a package, or one of its "sub-packages", then yes, String manipulation is your best bet.